# Google play services library not copying into lib folder..in Android project on Eclipse

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

After much searching for why my App is crashing on deploying on a device, while using Google Maps V2, I've discovered that, although I've imported the Google Play Services into my Workspace, and "adding" library, Google play services library is not appearing in my project's lib folder.
Anyone any idea why this is happening, and what the solution is??
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your logcat for crash.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

```
Create a new project

File -> New -> Android Application Project
You can leave all the options with their default values
Choose BlankActivity in the Create Activity screen

Ensure you have the latest version (v2) of the Google Play Services installed.

Select Window > Android SDK Manager or run android at the command line.
Scroll to the bottom of the package list and select Extras > Google Play services. The Google Play services SDK is downloaded to your computer and installed in your Android SDK environment at <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/

Add the Google Play Services project into your Eclipse workspace.

Click File -> Import..., select Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace
Browse to and select <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

To add the dependency to Google Play Services into your project

Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library, Add -> google-play-services_lib

Update MainActivity.java  to extend FragmentActivity instead of Activity
Check that Google Play Services is available on the device at runtime to protect against error cases
```

GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

```
Update res/layout/activity_main.xml and replace the entire contents with
```

android:id="@+id/map"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>

```
The map is controlled through the GoogleMap object, use findFragmentById to keep a reference to the GoogleMap from the layout.
```

GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))

```
           .getMap();
```

To use Google Maps API you need an API Key:

```
Go to the Google APIs Console
In Services enable ‘Google Maps Android API v2’ and agree to the terms
In the left navigation bar, click API Access.
Click Create New Android Key....
In the resulting dialog, enter the SHA-1 fingerprint, then a semicolon, then your application's package name. For example:

BB:0D:AC:74:D3:21:E1:43:67:71:9B:62:91:AF:A1:66:6E:44:5D:75;com.example.android.mapexample

If you have debug and production keys then add both in.

To obtain the SHA1 of your debug certificate use keytool:
```

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android -v

```
For Windows computers the .android directory is in your user directory
Your new API key will be a 40 character string like AIzbSyBaEqeUpYvlsbUe0OqTPn1-ABVMHVbdNxo

Add the following tag into your AndroidManifest.xml just before the closing </application> tag
```

android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"

android:value="your_api_key"/>

```
Your application now also needs the following permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml
```

```
     android:name="your_package_name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"

     android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
```

```
Optionally you can include one or both of these permissions to enable auto-location
```

```
Maps v2 uses OpenGl so the following uses-feature is also required
```

```
Test your application, checking the logcat output for any errors.
If it is working try out some of the other GoogleMap options:

mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
more details at
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views

Attribution Requirements. If you use the Google Maps Android API in your application, you must include the Google Play Services attribution text as part of a "Legal Notices" section in your application. Including legal notices as an independent menu item, or as part of an "About" menu item, is recommended. The attribution text is available by making a call to GooglePlayServicesUtil.getOpenSourceSoftwareLicenseInfo.

SOURCE: [HERE](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw)

Comment: Thanks - but I have a WORKING maps App created about 4 months ago, using all of the above.

Comment: My problem is that google-play-services-lib is NOT appearing in the newer App's LIB folder as a jar, even though I've obtained a green tick in the Properties/Android/Libraries add-on..